# how to use hooks for animation?

Tags: react-native

hello guys I am experimenting animation with Hooks and functional component 
it was working fine as expected but i have few confusion related to my code

let me explain

```
const [ProgressAnimation] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
```

using this to store animated value

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(ProgressAnimation, {
      toValue: progress,
      duration: 500,
    }).start();
  });
```

using effect to handle update progress bar so `progress` is local state updating every 500ms

```
const animatedWidth = ProgressAnimation.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, totalProgress],
    outputRange: ['0%', '100%'],
  });
```

my problem is that `progress` value set ever 500ms so i am rendering  every 500ms  i am doing it right or need to change the flow

sorry for my English.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail on what your desired outcome if for your animation? I'm a little unclear on how `progress` and `totalProgress` get set and what effect you're expecting when setting those. Also since you never use the `setter` half of the `ProgressAnimation` state you might consider `useRef` instead of `useState`.